# how to find and show by user in a simple node.js app?

Tags: javascript, node.js

**I trying to make a simple app in node and I have this as model:**

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");



var jobs = new mongoose.Schema({
    jobNumber: Number,
    jobField: String,
    jobTitle: String,
    jobCity: String,
    jobArea: String,
    jobAddress: String,
    jobPhone: String,
    jobInsurance: String,
    jobSalary: Number,
    jobAccommodation: String,
    jobDescription: String,
    author: {
        id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User"
        },
        username: String
    },

    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});



//EXPORT
module.exports = mongoose.model("jobs", jobs);
```

**and for router i have this:**

```
//SHOW OWNED JOBS
router.get("/myjobs", function (req, res) {

    jobs.find({},function (err, myjobs) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        } else {

            res.render("filteredJobs", {
                datas: myjobs
            });

        }
    });
});
```

**I can find some data by** *jobs.find{salaryJob : "900"}* **but if I want to find data by parameters of** *author* **how does it work?
I try several time like this but it doesn't work!**

```
//SHOW OWNED JOBS
router.get("/myjobs", function (req, res) {

    jobs.find({author.username : "blackcat"},function (err, myjobs) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        } else {

            res.render("filteredJobs", {
                datas: myjobs
            });

        }
    });
});
```

**thank you**

Answer (score 0):

right answer is:

{'author.username': String(req.user.username) } }

the problem was diferent between author.username and req.user.username, we should put a string here, I change the req.user.username to string with String(); function.